# Открыть таблицу из текстового файла с форматированием

Tags: delphi, excel

Есть файл .txt, внутри которого находится таблица в том виде, в котором надо отобразить в Экселе.
При использовании функции `xlsfile.Workbooks.Open(edit1.Text);` - где     `edit1.Text` - путь и имя текстового файла, возникает проблема с форматированием - строки не разделяются на столбцы. Вот как задать форматирование, как при открытии таблицы в Экселе( сначала, чтоб столбцы были фиксированной ширины, потом чтоб определенный столбец имел определенный формат данных)

Comment: Сделайте запись макроса в Excel'е. Потом откройте макрос, увидите какие параметры надо передавать в open.

Comment: Я бы с сделал, но не знаю, как

Comment: Закладка Вид. кнопка Макросы. Запись макроса. Дальше открывайте файл (устанавливайте там параметры). Потом опять Макросы-Остановить запись. Дальше Alt-F11, откроется редактор с макросом, там будут перечислены все параметры и нужные значения. Останется только их подставить в delphi. Проблема будет только с константами... В той книжке из ответа должно быть про них...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все сделать можно, но описывать много и долго.
скачай книгу **Разработка приложений Microsoft Office в Delphi**
и почитай там все описано.

[Программирование документов и приложений MS Office в Delphi](http://forcoder.ru/delphi/programmirovanie-dokumentov-i-prilozhenij-ms-office-v-delphi-255)

Comment: спасибо, почитаю